# Temporarily disable all onclick events and bind them back

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, bookmarklet

How to disable all onclick events on a page, bind my custom function, and after the execution enable all the previous events?

I'm building a bookmarklet, which should work on any already loaded page and I'm using jQuery to handle my custom logic (the page is jquerified after it is loaded). Note, that I don't have any control which events and when are being bound.

Currently the best stable solution i found is to unbind the events, bind by custom function preventing the default action and then, reload the page. This works, however I want to avoid the reload. A partial workaround would be to reload the page and scroll to the previous position (how to achieve this effect?). Some possible solution would use iframes, but I'd prefer to avoid this.

Comment: Show your current function.

Answer (score 6):

it's easier to lay a div-element over all... something like

**CSS**

```
.noclick {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 9999; /* or maybe higher */

    background-color: transparent;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('body').append('<div class="noclick" />');
});
```

Comment: what happens when the person tabs onto the page? You can still click on the elements with keyboard navigation. ;)

Answer (score 2):

A nice way I've seen it done, and done it myself is to use a modal 'mask' overlay.

The grayed out transparent mask that covers the entire page, except for the element you're interacting with, eg. modal popup window.

One more way is to use the [jQuery BlockUI plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/).

Answer (score 1):

You can reassign the onclick to another property and than override it.

Example with one element

```
var btn = document.getElementById("button");
btn._onclick = btn.onclick;
btn.onclick = function(){ return false; };
```

and when you want to transfer it back to the original event

```
var btn = document.getElementById("button");
if (btn._onclick) {
    btn.onclick = btn._onclick;
    btn._onclick = null;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, can you check your answer and fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether your onclick event is dependent on the element being clicked (i.e. whether it needs to know which element was clicked):

If it's independent, then you can just add an event handler to the body element or other parent (because the parent event gets called first, then the child, which is what you want):

```
$('body').click(function() { /* your code here */});
```

It it is dependent on the the element, then you can access the previous onclick event code that has been registered in the 'click' property of element which is being clicked, so something like this (probably being a little more specific with the selectors):

```
$('body *').each(function() {
  var previousClick = this.click;
  this.click = null; // remove previous
  $(this).click(function() { /* your code here */});
  $(this).click(function() { previousClick();}); // run the code that was already there.
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Some modification algorhythm's answer. 
The idea is to "cover" the link by a transparent element. You can use a pseudo element (e.g. **:after**).

To prevent "tab key" set tabindex:

`<a href="..." tabindex="-1">`

Mark link with a class "disabled" on click:

`$('a').on('click', function(){ $(this).addClass('disabled') })`

Add css:

`a.disabled:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background: white;
    opacity: 0.5; // optional 
    z-index: 999;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
  }`

```js
$('a').on('click', function(){ $(this).addClass('disabled') });
```

```css
a.disabled:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    background: white;
    opacity: 0.5; // optional 
    z-index: 999;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a hreh="#" tabindex="-1">The Link</a>
```